# PromQL: I want to calculate total http calls for specific time period grouped by status code

Tags: prometheus, promql

We have had an incident and I want to get total number of HTTP requests to a specific endpoint for a specific time period grouped by status code. For instance I want to know how many 500 response codes, 200 response codes, 400 response codes and so forth.

I have a query like the following:

```
sum by (status_code) (sum_over_time(http_requests_total{namespace="prod" , path="/register"}[3h20m]))
```

I do not know how to get it to ignore counts that happened before and after the incident. Is this even possible.

Comment: So, the PromQL query itself and the evaluation time are two things, see also https://www.robustperception.io/step-and-query_range and if you have some more time, maybe consider reading up a bit on how things work, using https://iximiuz.com/en/series/learning-prometheus-and-promql/?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas thanks for the URLs, it is hard to find in depth tutorials on PromQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute `sum_over_time()` with [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase), because `http_requests_total` is a [counter metric](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter).

For example, the following query should return the number of requests to `/register` path at `namespace="prod"` during the last 3 hours and 20 minutes grouped by `status_code`:

```
sum by (status_code) (
  increase(http_requests_total{namespace="prod" , path="/register"}[3h20m])
)
```

Comment: I added the offset to go back to incident date

Comment: The `offset` must be added just after square brackets: `increase(metric{filters}[lookbehind_window] offset duration)`